# Postgresql: Average for each day in interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table that is structured like this:

```
item_id    first_observed    last_observed    price
1          2016-10-21        2016-10-27       121
1          2016-10-28        2016-10-31       145
2          2016-10-22        2016-10-28       135
2          2016-10-29        2016-10-30       169
```

What I want is to get the average price for every day. I obviously cannot just group by `first_observed` or `last_observed`. Does Postgres offer a smart way of doing this?

The expected output would be like this:

```
date        avg(price)
2016-10-21  121
2016-10-22  128
2016-10-23  128
2016-10-24  128
2016-10-25  128
2016-10-26  128
2016-10-27  128
2016-10-28  140
2016-10-29  157
2016-10-30  157
2016-10-31  157
```

I could also be outputted like this (both are fine):

```
start       end         avg(price)
2016-10-21  2016-10-21  121
2016-10-22  2016-10-27  128
2016-10-28  2016-10-28  140
2016-10-29  2016-10-31  157
```

Comment: share your output

Comment: What is your expected output from this?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin OK, I have added it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=b8d6af28286fbc5705def2056a73f8be)

`generate_series` allows you to expand date ranges:

**First step:**

```
SELECT 
    generate_series(first_observed, last_observed, interval '1 day')::date as observed, 
    AVG(price)::int as avg_price
FROM items
GROUP BY observed
ORDER BY observed
```

1. expanding the date range
2. grouping the dates for AVG aggregate

**Second step**

```
SELECT 
    MIN(observed) as start,
    MAX(observed) as end,
    avg_price
FROM (
    -- <first step as subquery>
)s
GROUP BY avg_price
ORDER BY start
```

3. Grouping by avg_price to get the `MIN`/`MAX` date for it

Comment: I think your query is a lot cleaner and more readable than lau's query. Do you know if there is any performance difference?

Comment: The costs of my version are much lower: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=de06c5f40f58ed0d762cfeface4aa108

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH ObserveDates (ObserveDate) AS (
    SELECT * FROM generate_series((SELECT MIN(first_observed) FROM T), (SELECT MAX(last_observed) FROM T), '1 days')
)
SELECT ObserveDate, AVG(Price)
FROM ObserveDates
JOIN T ON ObserveDate BETWEEN first_observed AND last_observed
GROUP BY ObserveDate
ORDER BY ObserveDate
```